# Dynamic Movies using Artificial Intelligence

Tags: graph, artificial-intelligence, movie

I'm an AI Student, previously I was thinking about something, every time we guys we see a movie, the next time we the movie, it's the same thing, so those who have a knowledge of AI, such as the graph theory and so on, do you think it is feasible to create a dynamic movie, that is the first time you see it, it follows a path in the graph, the next time you see it, it follows a different path and as a result, we get a different movies, do u think this is feasible  ??

Comment: Are you talking alternative endings or minor changes ... like random extras doing slightly different stuff? Also: CG movies or real movies?

Comment: no it is completely a different path, of course, from one frame to another, there should be some linking but i think it is application for both CG and real movies, of course, if now we implement this movies, ordinary DVD player wont play it, because there would a program associated with the decision making so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shame I can't remember the French researcher who's doing research on movie style cameras. While not an interactive movie as you propose, you could alter the strength and importance of each character, and it would position, pan and zoom the camera according to cinematography rules. It looked very promising.

While it would show you the same movie, you could see it in infinitely different variants in regards to camera positioning, each of which could lead to a different interpretation :)

But for your proposal, just go with some logic based planning AI. No need for learning as others says. You have a bunch of sequences, and a bunch of logic to describe how they fit together, which prerequisites they have et cetera. If the logic is good, it would always result in a meaningful film. But it'd be a hard task. It's hard just to make a linear film ;)

(There's a whole chapter in Russel and Norvig)

Comment: Hey Planning is a good technique, i didn't thought about it,yes, i think using planning it is greatly feasible

Answer (score 1):

Where is an Intelligence in it? It looks like a bunch of ifs / switches with random.

The idea of AI is based on *learning*. Your AI component needs to adjust based on some external inputs, which I can't see in your description.

If the user could somehow tell your AI component that it likes / dislikes what he sees, than it will make sense. For example, you display a slideshow of photographs and the user tells you whether he likes or dislikes a photograph and you then choose future photographs based on his preference. You could learn from other user's preferences, too. That's AI.

Comment: if we use randomness then the film will be a complete disorder, we must make use of proper heuristics to move through the states in the graph so that there is a flow, thus making it having a flow is AI!! Of course, then  being able to know the likes of the user will be a greater advantage

Comment: No, the 'intelligence' is in the graph itself. You construct the static graph for possible and valid transitions between scenes. Later on you have just random choices which valid path to follow.

Comment: Yes, it is something like 1->(2,3,4), then we a random choice among 2,3,4

Comment: Yes, but as u say, if we get the likes of the user then make a decision, then may be it would be AI

Comment: Yes, it you get input from user and then change the behaviour based on this input than it would be fine: something like 1->(2,3,4), then choose among 2,3,4 based on previous choices